SharePoint embedded Power BI report not working with dynamic URL (using embed webpart)
I'm having an issue with a dynamic URL not working when added to a SharePoint page as an embed (using the Embed webpart, not the Power BI webpart). The URL is as follows:
https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId={id}&autoAuth=true&
filter=Products/Framework_x0020_Project_x0020_Code eq 'PF-R-0004'

This link works absolutely fine if pasted into the browser, filtering the report correctly. The only thing I can think of is the encoding of the filter, but the following does not work either:
filter=Products%2FFramework_x0020_Project_x0020_Code%20eq%20%27PF-R-0004%27

I've tried various other versions with more or less URL encoding but nothing seems to work in SharePoint, despite working directly in the browser.
Am I doing something wrong with the filter, or is this an unsupported feature? Plenty of sites seem to suggest it is (or at least was!) possible so I'm not quite sure what's happening.

After doing a bit more digging in developer tools (should really remember to use this more) it was struggling with the single quotes in the oData filter and no variation of escaping would return the correct URL.
The solution was to input the whole iframe (taken from what SharePoint generated) and use the fully encoded URL in that, which then worked fine. This has the added advantage of allowing you to tweak sizing as well, so a better solution overall.
